# Love you Worldbuilding, but I am hanging up my diamond

Tags: discussion

Been mulling this over for the past few months or however long its been, drama seems to stretch time out...

Anyway, **I am resigning my diamond**. I've been hoping to see things improve since Monica was fired and, well, it hasn't happened. Seeing Shog and Robert get unceremoniously fired by the company doesn't give me any hope that this pattern will change.

I've been around since the Area51 proposal and I have to say this has been an amazingly entertaining place to digitally hang out for the past few years. I have a hunch I will still be in chat but honestly with everything that has happened I just don't have any motivation to participate in the site anymore.  It's sad, and stupid that we have come to this point, but...here we are.

Good luck in whatever endeavors you take on World Builders. You are, without a doubt, the weirdest, most awesome, and...did I say weirdest already...community I have ever known.

Comment: There was never a time when we needed sensible, calm people more. To lose even one hurts the site more words can say. I suspect, I hope, WB will sail on, despite the nonsense inflicted on the SE network, and may continue to be awesomely strange in a creative way, I have enjoyed and valued your contribution to the site. Good luck and  all the best for the future.

Comment: James, thank you for all you have done for Worldbuilding, and I hope we meet again to build worlds on another platform.

Comment: Thanks for all you've done on the site James, was a pleasure working with you and all the other moderators.

Comment: So long, and thanks for all the fish.

Answer (score 33):

Honestly any sane organization would stop and think when they see people like yourself (and others) leave, and the fact that they don't seem to even know where the brake pedal is does not bode well.

I'd like to voice my appreciation for your hard work and calming voice on WB SE and wish you good luck.  Whatever site or sites elsewhere gets the benefit of your contributions will be very fortunate.

Comment: Thanks Stephen.

Comment: Corporate ledger hawks don't see people as people, they see them as "replaceable assets."  I  will suggest to you that their estimate is that someone else will want to do the job ...

Comment: SE is not a sane organization. I'm not sure why the rest of you are still here. Mass exodus is the only solution to bring down SE.

Answer (score -2):

Very sad that you are being made to feel this way.

Am glad to hear you'll still be around.  Just keep in mind: Stack Exchange is ***NOT*** the Company. Stack Exchange is us here in this community.

I've noticed a curious commonality between your, Tim's and Monica's resignation posts: all of you seem to be infected by the ill will coming from corporate. Frankly, as I said to the others, I didn't join SE to be part of an online Company. I didn't know what the Company was and didn't care; and I still don't know and don't care. I came here for the creativity and wonder demonstrated by all the community members who ask questions and offer answers. Period. Company policies and politics be damned. They're not the reason any of should be in this place!

Hopefully you can get over your corporatitis and feel free to just participate in the community itself!

Comment: As an interface between the company and the community our perspective is very different than the standard user. Providing unpaid, albeit volunteer labor to an organization is a whole lot easier when you respect the organization. I don't see the company making things better around the communities, but hey we are all welcome to our own opinions.

Comment: Fair enough. We're all unpaid labour here (my labour being to provide answers to people's questions). I'm not saying I don't "respect" the Company -- I just don't know anything about it and don't really care about it. I'm not an employee, not a shareholder and not a stakeholder. But I will take the downvotes as love notes coming from Corporate!

Comment: SE _is_ the company, at least it is now. There is no good reason for anyone to participate here anymore, except to crititicise the site leadership and call for Sara Chipps's dismissal.

Comment: @user91988 - Until and unless Corporate suspends my account, I hold that they have no bearing on my activity here, my reasons for being here in spite of what they've done to Monica and how they've made good community members feel. It's all a matter of perspective, and happily I am the one that gets to choose how I react to the company's shennanigans. In short, I choose not to be affected by them and in stead choose to focus on the community. Until they entirely screw things up and the whole platform disintegrates.

Comment: @elemtilas Except they have the right to distribute whatever you post, so they affect you greatly.